# How to hide master page control using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a DIV control's in Masterpage like below

```
<div id="div1" style="display: none">
<div id="div2" style="display: none">
<div id="div3" style="display: none">
```

i want to make it visible DIV control's in Masterpage  based on conditions in javascript from child page like below

```
function show()
{
    var prod = prdu(); // 1 or 2 or 3
    switch (prod) {
        case "1":                       
            document.forms[0].document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
            break;
    case "2":
            document.forms[0].document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";
            break;
    case "3":
            document.forms[0].document.getElementById("div3").style.display = "block";
            break;
    }

}
```

can you help in this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are close already. Remove the `document.forms[0].`, don't need that since getElementById searches for unique elements in the document anyway. Then change the display of the two not selected to `"none"` so only the one is visible.